# twitter bootstrap popover with content from database

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

**Summary**

I have a list generated from laravel. The badge icon contains a count of the number of tracks. When hovering over the badge I want to see a popover with a list containing the titles of those tracks (at most 5).

[image: List]

**Example**

To put it into context this is similar to Facebook's 'like' link. When a user hovers over the link, a tooltip is displayed with a list of friends that have also liked it.

[image: Facebook Like link]

**List set-up**

My list is generated by the code below. It is in the **{{ $tag->tracks->count() }}** where the badge content comes from.

```
<ul class="list-group">

    @foreach($user->tags as $tag)

    <li class="list-group-item">

        {{ link_to("tags/$tag->mdbid", "$tag->text") }}

        <a href="#">

            <span class="badge pull-right">

                {{ $tag->tracks->count() }}

            </span>

        </a>

    </li>

    @endforeach

</ul>
```

Comment: How's your list setup? I'm guessing you could use the objects properties to populate the text in the popover.

Comment: @NicklasWinger I've added the code for generating the list. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Well, I'm not really familiar with this syntax, but I guess you could foreach through all of your tags first of all. Then, in your popover use the $tag->name (or whatever the name of the property you're looking for) to display the relevant information.

Comment: Can the tooltip be placed on other elements instead of buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button type="button" class="badge btn btn-default" data-trigger="hover" 
 data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" 
 data-content="@foreach($tag->tracks as $track) {{ $track->title }} @endforeach">
   {{ $tag->tracks->count() }}
</button>
```